# How to make foreach iterator work after json has been deserialized to C# object?

Tags: c#, .net

I use this row to deserialize json:

```
YahooRootObject contacts = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<YahooRootObject>(stringToParse);
```

Here is the YahooRootObject:

```
public class YahooRootObject
{
    public YahooContacts contacts { get; set; }
}

internal class YahooField
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
    public string editedBy { get; set; }
    public List<object> flags { get; set; }
    public List<object> categories { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

internal class YahooContact
{
    public bool isConnection { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<YahooField> fields { get; set; }
    public List<object> categories { get; set; }
    public int error { get; set; }
    public int restoredId { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

internal class YahooContacts
{
    public List<YahooContact> contact { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public bool cache { get; set; }
}
```

After deserialization I want to use foreach iterator, for this purpose I need to implement enumerator on **contacts** object.

My question is how can I implement enumerator on **contacts** object to use foreach iterator?

Comment: What does JSON have to do with your problem? Why can't you just use foreach on the lists that are already there?

Comment: `foreach(var c in contacts.contact)` ?

Comment: At the moment you can write `foreach ( var c in root.contacts.contacts )`. What do you want to be able to write instead? Is the root object necessary in your API anyway if it only holds a single `YahooContacts` object?

Comment: I can't do that:
foreach(var c in contacts.contact)
I get this error:
'MvcContactsImporter.Models.DataTypes.Yahoo.API.YahooContacts' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `IEnumerable<YahooContact>` implementation to the `YahooContacts` class:

```
internal class YahooContacts : IEnumerable<YahooContact>
{
    public List<YahooContact> contact { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public bool cache { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<YahooContact> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return contact.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return contact.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```